# Should a vscode dev container run npm install as part of its setup?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I've created a VS Code [dev container](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers) for my project. To help new contributors get started, should the dev container Dockerfile run `npm install`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Dev container define a development environment and should not perform actions that would be part of a normal development workflow (such as running `npm install`).

There are a couple of reasons why `npm install` in particular should be avoided:

- If you run `npm install` in the dev container Dockerfile and it fails, the dev container will fail to launch. It's  farbetter if the developer can open the dev container successfully, and then run `npm install` in an environment where they can investigate potential failures
- `npm install` must be re-run when the project's dependencies change. Running `npm install` as part of dev container setup hides this from developers.

Dev container should only use `npm install` to install global scripts or tools that do not belong in the project's `package.json`.

Comment: To the point of that last sentence, I'm struggling to get azure-functions-core-tools NPM package to install when the devcontainer finishes building. I need to do this because I want to use the v3 version of the core tools and it's failing to install every time, unless I do so *manually* after the devcontainer boots. Suggestions?

Comment: Please try asking a separate question for that

Comment: So you answered your own question, nice! Thanks for the write up. Could you please provide a source of this information you gathered in your answer?

Answer (score 8):

It is actually good practice to call `npm install` as part of the dev container configuration. It eases and accelerate setup of the development environment, ensuring it's ready to use out of the box without extra steps possibly missed.

Note that the `npm install` must be in a `postCreateCommand` where sources and `package.json` are available (contrary to the `Dockerfile`).

Due to the nature of `docker` and `devcontainer`, there is very little reason for the `npm install` command to fail and need debugging. If it ever happen, VSCode logs will provide meaningful information, otherwise the `postCreateCommand` can be disabled quickly to investigate the issue.

There exists an official VSCode video, so we can assume calling `npm install` as part of the dev setup is a common practice: [How to automatically run npm install in a dev container](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9qRy_kxVCK8).